# HtmlAgilityPack Documentation

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am new to C#(started today) and I am trying to understand someone else's code which used the `HtmlDocument` class in HtmlAgilliyPack to parse HTML documents. I cannot find any documentation of this package. The [HtmlAgilityPack's project webpage](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/documentation) says that there is no documentation available.
If someone could point me to the documentation or explain the following methods(intermediate methods too) then that would be really helpful:

```
 - HtmlDocument.DocumentNode
 - HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.ssn
 - HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.GetElementbyId
 - HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.GetElementbyId(..).sns
 - HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.ssn(...).Attributes["value"].Value.ed().ns()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not understand the down votes. I have clearly stated the the _official_ webpage of a popular third party library doesn't provide and document. I have no where said that there are any bugs and I have only stated that I need help finding exact documentation and understanding the code. I will restate what I actually need by just copy pasting what I said. 'If someone could point me to the documentation or explain the following methods(intermediate methods too) then that would be really helpful'.

Comment: You got an upvote sir, for asking the right question and doubting the community where you are 'in my opinion' correct.

Comment: The downvotes are probably because *"...Questions asking us to recommend or **find a** book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."* Note the "find" part of that. You're asking where the documentation is, which makes the question off-topic. SO is not everything for everyone, some perfectly good questions in the general sense ("Where the heck are the docs?!") are off-topic for SO. A lot of people downvote off-topic questions. *(I didn't downvote it.)*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can download [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) Documents CHM file from [here](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/downloads/get/120935#).

If chm file contents are not visible then un-check `Always ask before opening this file` check-box as shown in screen shot

[image]

Note: The above dialog appears for unsigned files

[image]

UPDATE:

`HtmlAgilityPack` Documentation is available [here](https://html-agility-pack.net/documentation)

Comment: Thanks. There are certain methods e.g HtmlNode.sns() which the documentation does not explain...Is it outdated?

Comment: OK, I will search for it.

Comment: Is this really the quality of nuget packages? A broken chm provided in a link that can't be found anywhere? Downloaded the chm but it only gives me blank pages on windows 8.

Comment: @HMR You have to unblock the chm file after you download it [as explained here](https://www.google.fr/search?q=unblock+downloaded+file).

Comment: The CHM link above is no longer valid.  Any idea how I can get it? Thx

Answer (score 6):

CHM files [can be a hassle](https://superuser.com/q/126583). Check out [nudoq.com](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/HtmlAgilityPack/HtmlAgilityPack/HtmlDocument) - it combines API documentation with community comments (via Disqus). I've found its interface clean and easy to use.

Screenshot:

[image: Nudoq - HtmlDocument Example]

Comment: Nudoq seems to be no more.  Any idea where I can get the CHM or the same content that describes the entire object model?  The CHM link above is also outdated and the documentation on the site is too cursory.  Thx

Answer (score 1):

HTML Agility Pack massages an HTML document into looking like an XmlDocument.  Read the documentation on [XmlDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx) for these methods.

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful. I still couldn't find the explanation for ed() method in it.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is now available here https://html-agility-pack.net/documentation

Comment: And it is sadly incomplete.