# Parse HTML in c#

Tags: c#, html, wpf, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

So i am trying to get `SCN08_SS_GetCustomer_CAM` from this html code.

```
<tr>
    <td class="line2left bordered">
      <div class="tablelabel typped virtualuser" style="margin-left:00px">SCN08_SS_GetCustomer_CAM</div>
    </td>
    <td class="line2right bordered">875.2</td>
    <td class="line2right bordered">875.2</td>
    <td class="line2right bordered">875.2</td>
    <td class="line2right bordered">1</td>
    <td class="line2right bordered">0</td>
    <td class="line2right bordered">0</td>
    <td class="line2right bordered"></td>
</tr>
```

I am basically building a desktop application using WPF. Coding in .net c#. 
In htmlagilitypack there is a way to getelementyid but no getelementbyclass. And in this html code there is no id. Hence i will have to get it by class. 
So any ideas on how to code this guys?

Comment: You can parse it using `HtmlAgilityPack` as `document.SelectNodes("//div[@class='tablelabel typped virtualuser']")`

Comment: To get `HtmlAgilityPack's Documentation`, take a look at [HtmlAgilityPack Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32110833/htmlagilitypack-documentation/32111784#32111784)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice and simple application

```
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.Load(@"pathtoyourpage.html");
var result = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='tablelabel typped virtualuser']").InnerText;
Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
```

Haven't tested it though