# DOM Traversal in .mht saved webpage

Tags: .net, powershell, dom, mhtml

Is it possible to do DOM traversal in a webpage saved as .mht, or saved as .htm (html only)?
Preferably in powershell or .net
Goal is to be able to do something like `getElementsByTagName('div')`
If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution using [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).
Documentation can be found on [NuDoq](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/HtmlAgilityPack/HtmlAgilityPack/HtmlDocument), which was mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32110833/htmlagilitypack-documentation).

Example code:

```
# Choose a source
$Source = 'C:\temp\myFile.mht'
$Source = 'http://www.google.com'

# Get online or mht content
$IE = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application

# Don't show the browser
$IE.Visible = $false

# Browse to your webpage/file
$IE.Navigate($Source)

# Wait for page to load
while ($IE.busy) { Sleep -Milliseconds 50 }

# Get the html from that page
$Html = $IE.Document.body.parentElement.outerHTML

# Decode to get rid of html encoded characters like &amp; etc...
$Html = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode($Html)

# Close the browser
$IE.Quit()


# Use HtmlAgilityPack (must be installed first)
Add-Type -Path (Join-Path $Env:userprofile '.nuget\packages\htmlagilitypack\1.4.9.5\lib\Net40\HtmlAgilityPack.dll')
$Hap = New-Object HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument

# Load the Html in HtmlAgilityPack to get a DOM
$Hap.LoadHtml($global:Html)

# Retrieve the data from the DOM (read a node)
[string]$partData = $Hap.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='formatted_content']/ul").InnerText
```