# Why does this help file that I downloaded from the Internet only contain blank pages?

Tags: windows, winapi, chm

I'm trying to debug come code that uses [WINIO](http://www.internals.com/utilities_main.htm), but unfortunately I can't find any good explanation on what it's supposed to be doing.  The standard download comes with a CHM helpfile, but just to add insult to injury, *every page of the helpfile is blank!*

[image]

Is there something wrong with the help file, or is it really meant to be full of empty pages?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening a CHM file produces: "navigation to the webpage was canceled"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438634/opening-a-chm-file-produces-navigation-to-the-webpage-was-canceled)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've already got the documentation. It's that help file. But the help file was downloaded from the web and your computer knows this and doesn't want to show the HTML until you tell it to trust it.

Right click on the .chm file and select Properties.

[image]

Then click the Unblock button.

[image]

Then open the help file again and you can see the content.

[image]

Comment: ...and suddenly I have documentation.  Thanks!  Man, it would sure be nice if `hh.exe` *actually told you about that!*

Answer (score 0):

Since this is stackoverflow, here's a programmatical solution, in Delphi (from FPC's winutils unit)

```
procedure UnBlockFile(const name:String);
var f : file;
begin
 assignfile(f,name+':Zone.Identifier');
 rewrite(f,1);
 truncate(f);
 closefile(f);
end;
```

Comment: Easier to call `DeleteFile`

Comment: I looked it up, and indeed deletefile also is supposed to support alternate streams. Thanks!