# HTML Help workshop

Tags: html, chm, html-help-workshop

When I open the help (.chm) application, I could see table of contents. By default, the first entry in the file is selected, however I couldn't see the corresponding page data. Instead, I see "This program cannot display the web page" (the default error message that comes in IE7).The page is displayed only when I click on any of the contents on the left side.

Is there a way of showing the page by default without clicking on the entry?

Comment: "The help application" of what exactly? Some .chm file you created yourself? Or of something existing? Is this a user support request or a programming question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening a CHM file produces: "navigation to the webpage was canceled"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438634/opening-a-chm-file-produces-navigation-to-the-webpage-was-canceled)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft introduced some security restrictions many years ago that disable functionality in HTML Help files that are accessed over a network, so what you're seeing is almost certainly by design. There are two possible solutions: move the help file to your local drive, or implement some changes in the Windows registry so that you can view the contents of remote help files.

Microsoft's summary of the problem: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896054

You may try following workaround that lets you explicitly 'unblock' a CHM help file coming from a network drive or internet download. To do this:

- Open Windows Explorer
- Find your CHM file
- Right click and select Properties
- Click the Unblock button on the General tab

For information on how to make the registry changes, see this page:
http://www.grainge.org/pages/authoring/chm_mspatch/896358.htm

Or more straightforwardly, use the free HHReg utility available from the page below to make the required changes.
http://www.ec-software.com/products_hhreg.html