# Cannot see the contents of the HTML help for Virtual TreeView

Tags: html-help

I download Virtual TreeView from https://www.jam-software.com/virtual-treeview/ . After I open the HTML Help inside it, I get a warning, then I proceed and will see the table of contents in the left panel, I can also search in the help. However, whenever I try to click the item in the left panel, there are nothing appear in the left panel. What I can see is just a white background. This problem only occurs in Windows 7.

I try to open the same HTML help in WIndows XP, then I will be able to see the content in the right panel.

Why?

Answer (score 1):

The solution can be found in [Opening a CHM file produces: "navigation to the webpage was canceled"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438634/opening-a-chm-file-produces-navigation-to-the-webpage-was-canceled/11438732#11438732) . I try to unblock the file and then be able to view the contents.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.