# How to use Inno Setup XDELTA patch maker

Tags: installation, inno-setup, patch

I have downloaded this from https://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Patchers/Inno-Setup-XDELTA-Patch-Maker.shtml

Its a patch addon for Inno setup to make incremental patch installers easy to do, but..

There are no instructions, and I don't see how to even get it running. There are no links to the creator so I cannot ask them.

Comment: The zip file download of that tool contains a CHM help file. You will need to consult that for how to use the tool and for contact information.

Comment: Thanks Bill, When I open the help file with the Windows help app, it doesn't display anything behond the section titles.

Comment: That might be because of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400744/chm-viewer-unable-to-show-contents ?

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thank you.

However the now readable help file contains nothing about how to install and run.